# ajax - return and prevent deferred.then() execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a AJAX request like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: url,
   dataType: "json", 
   success: function(data) {
      // ...
      callbak(true);
   },

  })
  .then( 
    function( response ) {
        // ...
    });
```

I'd like to run that callback function and so exit from that ajax request in `success` function and prevent `deferred.then()` execution.
In my case the `callback` is fired but after that `deferred.then()`  is also executed and I don't want this to happen.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want run the `then` callback only on failure then? Why won't you use the `error` callback?

Comment: @gdoron there is come code I did not write, but I can't use `error` because in some cases the `data` value is empty but the `success` function is fired and I need to exit from the ajax request.

Comment: Your question I'm afraid is still very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag like so:

```
var executeThen = true;
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            // ...
            executeThen = false;
            callbak(true);
        },

    })
    .then(function(response) {        
        if(executeThen){
         // ...
        }
    });
```